# How To Create A Fixed Width Element

Tags: php, css, wordpress, themes

I have a full width page template in wordpress and have created a box inside this through a plugin. However, I need the box to have the text wrapping around this. The plugin developer has said to wrap the text inside a fixed width element. For this I am a little confused and any help would be greatly appreciated. The page in question is http://www.haylockpittman.co.uk/refurbishment-and-renovation-of-kitchens/

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You are applying a width to the child DIV when you should be applying to the parent.

Your CSS selector currently reads

```
.grid3 .content_block
```

If you changed this to `.content_block_wrapper.grid-3` and added a `float:left;` it will work. You will also need to remove the `<div class="clearboth"></div>` you have below your container.

Comment: Thank for the advice, I am slightly confused how to change this thought as looking through the stylesheet I cannot find the div class .grid3 .content_block The <div class="clearboth"></div> appears to be put in there by the plugin so I am not 100% sure how I can change it. Sorry for the ignorance but my knowledge of css is pretty poor

Comment: One of the suggestions (by @davidpauljunior) has a simpler method to the solution I provided. However if you can't remove the `<div class="clearboth"></div>` then it will force the paragraphs to drop below your fixed width section.

Could your plugin developer remove the `clear` in this case?

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunatly it is a plugin from code canyon and the developer wont help so I am trying to work around this. I might need to look into the plugin css and work out how to remove it. Thanks again for your suggestions

Comment: If that `<div class="clearboth"></div>` has to be there (from the plugin), you'l have to target it in the CSS and add a rule `.clearboth { clear: none; }`.

Answer (score 0):

try this if you don't knew it already :

```
<div style="position:fixed;">
    this is a fixed area 
    </div>
```

Comment: Thanks NumOne, I just tried that but the box gets locked to the bottom of the screen. I am sure I have missed something obvious but not sure what though

Answer (score 0):

I think the simplest way is to change this html:

```
<div class="content_block_wrapper grid3 clearfix">
```

to this:

```
<div class="grid3">
```

And then remove the `<div class="clearboth"></div>` the lives just after the `<div>` above closes.

You'll probably want a margin to the right of that box, so add that to CSS for the `.content_block general-2`